# Mongorestore in a python script with host predicate

Tags: python, mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Bonjour,
I want to `mongorestore` a `dump` from an `azure VM` toward a `cosmosDB` account. I can do it from command line with `stg` like this :

```
mongorestore --host <url>:10255 -u <secret> -p <secret> --ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates ./dump/ --numInsertionWorkersPerCollection 40 --batchSize 2
```

but I can't do it within [python](/questions/tagged/python) :

```
>>> os.execvp('mongorestore',['-h <url>:10255 -u <secret> -p <secret> --ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates ./dump/ --numInsertionWorkersPerCollection 40 --batchSize 2'])
2018-12-14T12:31:29.163+0000    Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
```

or even in a most modern way, with subprocess, same thing :(

Answer (score 1):

I tried to realize your needs using `Python 3.6` on my local machine, and my sample code works fine as below, which use the `subprocess.Popen` method.

```
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.Popen('mongorestore --host 127.0.0.1:27017 ./dump/ --numInsertionWorkersPerCollection 40 --batchSize 2')
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x0000025E2D9B0AC8>
>>> 2018-12-19T14:56:40.687+0800        preparing collections to restore from
2018-12-19T14:56:40.688+0800    done
```

Or to use `os.popen` also works as same as `subprocess.Popen`.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.popen('mongorestore --host 127.0.0.1:27017 ./dump/ --numInsertionWorkersPerCollection 40 --batchSize 2')
<os._wrap_close object at 0x0000025E2D9BE5C0>
>>> 2018-12-19T15:00:55.372+0800        preparing collections to restore from
2018-12-19T15:00:55.373+0800    done
```

Hope it helps.